# taking all http file requests in .html files to the https file requests using htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess, web

I have a site, basically a board.
I want to take all "http" requests, including ones that are in the HTML files, the user's signatures and want to get the "https" requests of them to maintain security of the site

Like if the site is **https**://xxxx.yyy and its file contains a link to an image at **http**://aaaa.bbb, then basically, if I try to use https with the file, it will give a "not secure error" as there is one element with "http".

I want to modify the .htaccess to take all such **http**://aaaa.bbb requests and get the **https**://aaaa.bbb requests of them, so that the site is still shown as secure in the padlock.